# screen freezing while moving large files to external disk

Tags: kernel, nautilus

I have Ubuntu 13.04, while moving large files to external disk using Nautilus or Thunar screen is freezing, I have to push power button to reboot.
I have 3.8.0-34-generic kernel installed. Would you please help me debug the problem?
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while and I forgot about my topic here. I luckily found that after removing `usbmount`, file transfer speed increased and no freezing anymore.